# Self-closing if statement/loop

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have the following if condition:

```
function turnLedOn1(evt) {
    led.on();
    var executed = false;
    if (!executed) {
        executed = true;
        checkin1 = timestamp;
        alert('checkin1');
    }
}
```

The if loop should only be executed once, but i get like 15 alerts until it stops. Does anybody have an idea why?

Comment: Can you post the code that calls `turnLedOn1(evt)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place `var executed = false;` outside of your function closure.

```
var executed = false;
function turnLedOn1(evt) {
    led.on();
    if (!executed) {
        executed = true;
        checkin1 = timestamp;
        alert('checkin1');
    }
}
```

When a variable is declared in a function, it can only be read from that 'closure'. When the function runs again, the variable is reset because `var ... = false;` is run again. [More about closures.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 0):

you are setting executed to false and then checking to see if it is false :)
   try putting var executed = false global outside the function.

```
 var executed = false;
 if (!executed) {
    ...
 }
```

regards